# Decode JSON array of objects in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

Given this parameter I am not able to decode the JSON:

`workflowParams: '[{"name":"abc-image-tag","value":"0123"},{"name":"cde-image-tag","value":"0"}]'`

Using this code:

```
{{- $params := $data.workflowParams | fromJson -}}
{{- $params | toJson }}
```

throws the following error: **"json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}"**

I don't understand what's wrong with this code, as the resulting object clearly should be an array of maps of which I want to extract the value in a loop.

Comment: See this [example](https://helm-playground.com/#t=LQhQG9wAgMwJwPYFsBSBnBA7KA6AagIYA2ArgKZo4AmBALgVAL6MTS0Lpa6GkXV0NmrWIlQZMAQThwCAT27FylGvSYtII5J0nS5C3soFQAPlHba1oIA&v=LQhQBMEMBdILgAQHIDaBvARAO0gWwKYZwaQBGAxsAJa6QDm%2BwsdGANBgG6QA2ArocQAMARgBMAZgwBfVphwEiGcuEY16jZm049%2BiwdIC6SIA) with [`fromJsonArray`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#fromjsonarray).

Comment: See [Type Conversion Functions](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions).

Comment: How are you trying to use the value?  If you're just trying to write out a value, could you evaluate `$data.workflowParams` without parsing and reserializing it?  Or if you're trying to do more computation on it, would it make sense to make the Helm value be a list of objects, rather than a JSON-encoded string?